# I saw in another forum that this issue was made, but was not answered. I'm creating a reactionroles system but embeds sends but role isn't given

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a reaction roles system for my discord server, but I'm experiencing a major issue, I'm assuming minor to most. So my bot successfully sends the embeds with the corresponding emojis for the roles, but when user reacts to the emoji the role isn't given. Does anyone have any issue to this?

````
    name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = "971301182540771328";
        const retail = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Retail");
        const consoles = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Consoles");
        const gpus = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "GPUs");
        const footsiteRestocks = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Footsite Restocks");
        const shopify = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Shopify");
        const reminders = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Reminders");
        const aco = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "ACO");
        const groupbuys = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Groupbuys");
        const members = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Members");
        

        const retailEmoji = '';
        const consolesEmoji = '️';
        const gpusEmoji = '️';
        const footsiteRestocksEmoji = '';
        const shopifyEmoji = '';
        const remindersEmoji = '⏰';
        const acoEmoji = '';
        const groupbuysEmoji = '';
        const memberssEmoji = '❗';

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('5104DB')
        .setTitle('Select Your Roles!')
        .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/931332825360269333/938631314133909574/Logo_v3.png')
        .addFields(
            { name: '', value: 'Retail', inline: true },
            { name: '️', value: 'Console Pings', inline: true },
            { name: '️', value: 'GPU Pings', inline: true },
            { name: '', value: 'Footsite Restocks', inline: true },
            { name: '', value: 'Shopify Pings', inline: true },
            { name: '⏰', value: 'Reminders', inline: true },
            { name: '', value: 'ACO Updates', inline: true },
            { name: '', value: 'Groupbuys', inline: true },
            { name: '❗', value: "If you don't see any channels", inline: true },
        )
        .setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Boombap\'s Cookout', iconURL: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/931332825360269333/938631314133909574/Logo_v3.png'});

        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
        messageEmbed.react(retailEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(consolesEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(gpusEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(footsiteRestocksEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(shopifyEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(remindersEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(acoEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(groupbuysEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(memberssEmoji);

        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === retailEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(retail);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === consolesEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(consoles);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === gpusEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(gpus);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === footsiteRestocksEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(footsiteRestocks);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === shopifyEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(shopify);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === remindersEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(reminders);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === acoEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(aco);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === groupbuysEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(groupbuys);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === memberssEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(members);
                }
                
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
        client.on("messageReactionRemove", async(reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === retailEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(retail);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === consolesEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(consoles);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === gpusEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(gpus);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === footsiteRestocksEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(footsiteRestocks);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === shopifyEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(shopify);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === remindersEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(reminders);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === acoEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(aco);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === groupbuysEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(groupbuys);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === memberssEmoji){
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(members);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an event inside a command like that.
Learn about collectors here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors

Comment: The code worked just fine, I was missing intents.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the post, after reviewing the code, I was missing a specific intents in my index.js. The intents missing was "Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS".